# Python's collection.Counter equivalent in C# or .NET

Tags: python, c#, dictionary, hashmap, counter

I was solving some problems on LeetCode, while solving the problem in Python I often had to use Python's `collections.Counter` object.

When I started solving the same problems in C# I couldn't find an equivalent method or class for it.

I was just wondering if there is any?

#### Explanation of `collections.Counter`

Python's `collections.Counter` takes in an iterable and returns a hash-map, where the keys are all the unique elements of the original iterable and the corresponding value is the number of times that key appears in the original iterable.

Comment: You might want to describe what it does. C# folks don't all speak Python

Comment: Looking at the docs (https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), Nope, there is no C# equivalent. It would be pretty easy to write. Don't subclass `Dictionary<TKey, int> though, make that a private member

Comment: well that's a bummer :(

Comment: Check out the [`CountBy`](https://morelinq.github.io/3.4/ref/api/html/Overload_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_CountBy.htm) operator from the [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) package.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a performant implementation of a `ToCounter` LINQ operator, that takes an enumerable sequence and returns a dictionary with the elements of the sequence as keys. The `int` value of the resulting dictionary represents the number of times each element appears in the `source` sequence:

```
public static Dictionary<TSource, int> ToCounter<TSource>(
this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
IEqualityComparer<TSource>? comparer = default) where TSource : notnull
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);

    Dictionary<TSource, int> dictionary = new(comparer);
    foreach (TSource item in source)
    {
        CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault(dictionary, item, out _)++;
    }
    return dictionary;
}
```

The [`CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.getvaluereforadddefault) is an advanced API, that allows to add or update a dictionary with a single [`GetHashCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1.gethashcode) invocation for the key. The default value of the `int` type is `0`, which makes the implementation pretty simple (no need to declare a [ref local variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/declarations#reference-variables)).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a real quick implementation of a class that does what you are thinking about.  Feel free to add some extra features:

```
public class CountedCollection<T> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, int>>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<T, int> _countDictionary;

    public CountedCollection()
    {
        if (!typeof(IEquatable<T>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"The type {typeof(T).Name} must implement IEquatable of <{typeof(T).Name}> to be usable with CountedCollection");
        }
        _countDictionary = new Dictionary<T, int>();
    }

    public CountedCollection(IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        _countDictionary = new Dictionary<T, int>(comparer);
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        ++TotalCount;
        if (_countDictionary.TryGetValue(item, out var curCount))
        {
            _countDictionary[item] = ++curCount;
        }
        else
        {
            _countDictionary.Add(item, 1);
        }
    }

    public void Add (IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            Add(item);
        }
    }

    public int TotalCount { get; private set; } = 0;
    public int DistinctCount => _countDictionary.Count;

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<T, int>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var item in _countDictionary)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

It's very lightly tested.

It implements the "Collection Initialization Pattern" and it can be initialized with an existing collection, so both of these work (the second one initializes it using an array of integers):

```
var dict1 = new CountedCollection<string> { "abc", "xyz", "abc", "123" };
var dict2 = new CountedCollection<int> { new[] { 34, 12, 65, 12, 101 } };
```

The class provides two constructors.  If `T` doesn't implement `IEquatable<T>`, then you can provide your own implementation of an `IEqualityComparer<T>`.  This also allows you to do case independent counting of instances.  For example:

```
var dict3 = new CountedCollection<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
{ 
    "abc", 
    "xyz", 
    "ABC", 
    "123", 
    "Xyz"
};
```

That code will show two instances of "abc" and two instances of "xyz".

Because you can bring your own `IEqualityComparer<T>`, `T` is not constrained to implement `IEquatable<T>`, the first constructor will throw an `ArgumentException` if `T` fails to implement `IEquatable<T>` (things must be comparable for equality somehow).

For example, this will throw:

```
var dict4 = new CountedCollection<CountedCollection<string>>();
```